# Dynamically importing components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-import

I have just been getting my hands dirty with react-js and have come across this piece of code for dynamically importing components in my app which I cant seem to understand?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class Dynamic extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { module: null };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { path } = this.props;
    import(`${path}`)
      .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))
  }
  render() {
    const { module: Component } = this.state; // Assigning to new variable names @see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
    return(
      <div>
        {Component && <Component />} // the code i can't figure out
    //{Component} works fine too
       //{<Component />} gives error
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Dynamic path='./FirstComponent' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Can someone please explain the line of code which i have highlighted it looks to me some kind of conditional rendering but as far as i know it works like if the left hand evaluates to true the right hand is rendered but why is this code working with only {Component} as well?

Comment: Because at initial render `{Component} `evaluates to `null`

Comment: @JSEngine so thats why {<Component />} returns error?

Comment: can you please explain a little it would be nice to now the actual flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at initial render `{Component}` evaluates to null.
As you have used destructuring.

`const { module: Component } = this.state;`

so

```
 Component = null
```

But when you use `<Component/>` at initial render there is no `<Component/>` component. So using `{ <Component />}` gives error.

Using `Component` and `<Component/>` are different.

Comment: ok so how do you explain the line  {Component && <Component />}? at the inital render Component is null so <Component /> wont get rendered?

Comment: it will evaluate to `{ null && <Component ./>}` so before `&&` operator there is null  means false so it will not evaluate the code after `&&`  operator

Comment: all right cheers man one more thing the code works fine if i replace the line with only {Component} i just want to know is this right and will it work fine when state is changed and all that?

Comment: i would say go with `{Component && <Component />} `

Comment: if you use only `{Component}` it will run fine at initial render but will give you error at second render because at that time `{Component}` evalutates to object if  module.default is a  class component or function component

Comment: yeah was just going to post about it after playing around with the code.Thanks man

Comment: It's my pleasure